# Asus x550: unstable wireless connection

Tags: wireless, networking, asus

I've been getting weak signal to my asus x550 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. As suggested by someone in Askubuntu.. I've got a good signal but wifi keeps disconnecting automatically for every 5minutes or so.

I've ran [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) script and here is the link for the results http://paste.ubuntu.com/7847358/ . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your dmesg output has numerous failures and errors.

I would try to reinstall the drivers for the device. If that doesn't work, upgrade to the newest kernel and then reinstall the drivers.  I had this same issue after a cleam install of 14.04 and had to reinstall the drivers with the latest kernel to correct my issue, granted, I have a different wireless device, so I can't promise you anything.  This is just due diligence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my asus X550LA and I could not solve, but the upgrade from ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 and all my drivers worked properly, including wifi.